# Make nginx reverse proxy 302 redirect to a URI sub-folder instead of root

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a web server on my LAN with the URL `https://10.0.0.22` and I am trying to access it from the internet through an nginx reverse proxy with a URL like `https://domain.com/my/web/app`.

The difficulty I'm having is that the local server sends a 302 redirect to `/login.php`, which nginx then passes back to the external client's browser to become `https://domain.com/login.php` instead of `https://domain.com/my/web/app/login.php`. This results in a 404 error because there's nothing at `https://domain.com/login.php`.

I have tried many different options with little success, including a wide range of `rewrite`, `proxy_redirect`, and `proxy_buffering` directives, but this is as close as I can get it:

```
    location ^~ /my/web/app/
    {
            proxy_buffering   off;
            rewrite           /my/web/app/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass        https://10.0.0.22/;
    }
```

Is there a way to configure nginx so that the internal web server's 302 redirect to  `/login.php` manifests externally as `/my/web/app/login.php`?

Comment: This might help, but I have not tried it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695630/best-method-of-post-processing-nginx-reverse-proxy-response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After continued investigation and testing of different combinations and ordering of directives, adding [`proxy_redirect`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect) after the `proxy_pass` directive seems to fix the URI translation issue:

```
 proxy_redirect https://10.0.0.22/ https://domain.com/my/web/app/;
```

After some more tinkering, it seems that setting `proxy_redirect` to `default` does the same thing implicitly:

```
 proxy_redirect default;
```

The full location block then looked like this:

```
location ^~ /my/web/app/
{
        proxy_buffering   off;
        rewrite           /my/web/app/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass        https://10.0.0.22/;
        #proxy_redirect    https://10.0.0.22/ https://domain.com/my/web/app/;
        proxy_redirect    default;
}
```

Images were still broken, however, because they point to `/images` on the local server. I'm not sure of how to get nginx to translate those (because they're embedded in the HTML body) but to work around the problem for now, I was able to add a dedicated `location` block for `/images` *before* the location block for `/my/web/app`, like this:

```
    location ^~ /images/
    {
            proxy_pass https://10.0.0.22/images/;
            proxy_redirect default;
    }
```